# How do we compare models of ETCS?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, elementary-theory-category-of-sets, lo.logic

The elementary theory of the category of sets ([nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS)) gives axioms on a category such that it is a category of sets. In answering [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42590/independence-and-category-theory/42708#42708) I realised that we might have trouble comparing different models of ETCS. So here are some questions starting with easy ones (which I should know the answer to!) to the more difficult.

1. Are two models of ETCS necessarily equivalent categories?
2. Are two models of ETCS equivalent as well-pointed topoi with NNO and Choice?
3. Is there a functor (Edit: a logical functor, as Todd pointed out) between any two models of ETCS? A span?
4. Do models of ETCS necessarily even belong to the same category?

I wonder, because the sets that one model of ETCS has as hom-objects may be completely different to the sets that the other model has as hom-objects, and there is a priori no way to map between them.

Comment: For question 3, surely you mean not just "functor", but a "logical functor" which preserves finite limits, power objects, and natural numbers object? I'm not even sure what you mean by 4 (I mean, why not: just take objects to be ETCS categories and morphisms to be logical functors)? 

Comment: Hmm, re 4: I suppose so. But are there many arrows in this category? Is it connected? I could be completely naive and ask: is there a weakly initial object? (The constructible universe, perhaps?)

Comment: And regarding 3: I really meant, 'is there a functor?', but this would allow silly functors like those mapping everything to the empty set. Let us say at least preserving finite limits. The flavour of set theory one is using clearly affects things like NNOs, as Joel pointed out (and I was aware of to begin with).

Comment: You probably want more than preservation of finite limits since otherwise you could just map everything to the terminal object. Being a category theorist, I think "logical functor" seems like a natural choice. If that is the choice, I believe there is no weakly initial object (and I could maybe rummage up some relevant nLab pages). 

Comment: I don't know anything at all about ETCS. Is it the "elementary theory" of the "category of sets", as in the model-theoretic term "elementary diagram"? 

Comment: "Elementary" here refers to a theory which doesn't make reference to an external notion of set in the background. For example, when we refer to a small or locally small category, we refer to a background notion of set, whereas here the development is to be independent of any such prior notion. The terminology is due to Lawvere. 

Answer (score 7):

(Caveat: I come from set theory rather than category theory and know only a little about ETCS.)

The answer to your question is no. The basic reason is that even the models
of set theory themselves can differ vastly. If $M$ is a
model of ZFC, then the category $Set^M$, which is Set as
interpreted in $M$, will be a model of ETCS. But if ZFC is
consistent, then the models of set theory $M$ are diverse.
For example, some have CH and others have $\neg CH$, and
furthermore, by the incompleteness theorem, they can
satisfy different arithmetic statements. Such statements
show up in the category $Set^M$, since every
arithmetic statement (first order statement about natural
numbers) has a translation into the formal language of
ETCS. So in general these categories are not elementary equivalent in the language of ETCS. In particular, the natural numbers objects of such categories will not in general be isomorphic, and so there can be no nice functors between the categories. For example, by the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, some models of set theory will be countable and others will have an uncountable set of natural numbers, with a different theory, and these aspects will prevent their corresponding Set categories from being equivalent as categories or from having nice functors. In
general, it will not be possible to map the natural number
object from one to the other in any nice way.

Comment: But you can't even talk about the isomorphism or otherwise of two $\mathbb{N}^M$ as they are objects of different categories. And one can legitimately talk about a functor that maps the NNO from one model to the other model: a functor doesn't give a function from one NNO to the other after all. One _would_ need, OTOH, a map $End(\mathbb{N}^{M_1}) \to End(\mathbb{N}^{M_2})$, for example. If the functor preserved NNOs, then it might be a bit tricky, but I don't have any idea what would happen then.

Comment: Arg, what happened to the LaTeX in my comment?

Comment: I agree this answers questions 1 and 2. I think there is some lingering question as to what one takes the morphisms between models of ETCS to be; for a category theorist, the notion of "logical functor" would be a natural choice, but a model theorist might gravitate toward something else (like elementary equivalence?). The answer to question 3 might depend on what one chooses. Logical functors preserve truth but do not necessarily reflect truth, so they can sometimes map one NNO to another even if the NNOs have somewhat different properties. 

Comment: The two Set's are two different categories, and you are asking for a functor between them. My point is that if the functor is at all nice, then this induces an isomorphism of the natural number objects with their successor functions, or at least an embedding from one to the other,  which can be impossible. The isomorphism does not live in either of these categories, but in the set-theoretic background where the functor lives. In any case, the two models can have different arithmetic truths, and this arises in the theory of the categories, so they needn't be elementarily equivalent.

Comment: David, it is sensible to compare the natural number objects of two different models of ZFC, since these are just two models of PA, which can be considered (set-theoretically) outside of the context of the models of set theory in which they live. 

Comment: Ah, I see now that perhaps you are confused and thought I was changing the ambient set-theoretic background, but no, I just mean to consider two set models of ZFC, which have different arithmetic truth. Thus, we get two categories of ETCS that are inequivalent as categories.

Comment: Todd, won't logical functors be fully truth-preserving for first-order arithmetic truth on the NNOs themselves, since full first order arithmetic truth corresponds to $\Delta_0$ truth in the larger structure, as all quantifiers are bounded by the NNO itself? That is, logical functors are $\Delta_0$-elementary on the full category, and this means fully first order elementary for arithmetic truth, right?

Comment: Joel, it would take me quite a while to wrap my head around the question you just put to me, as we come perhaps from different mathematical cultures and my set theory is not particularly strong. So instead of trying to tackle your question head-on, I'll try to give the flavor of what I have in mind using slightly different examples from topos theory. There it is quite possible to construct a logical functor $f: E \to E'$ which takes the NNO of $E$ to the NNO to $E'$, but without one NNO being embedded in the other. For example, if $E$ is the topos Set/2 and $E'$ is Set, the NNO of $E$ (cont.)

Comment: ...is $N \times 2 \to 2$, and the logical functor $f: E \to E'$ given by pulling back along one of the elements $1 \to 2$ preserves NNO. (If it helps, you can think of $E'$ as a universe of Boolean-valued sets where the truth values lie in the Boolean algebra $P(2)$.) Internal to $E'$, the elements of its NNO are pairs of ordinary natural numbers; this NNO does not embed in the NNO of $E$. Now this example may seem unfair since $E'$ is not a model of ETCS, but suffice it to say that I have many such examples from topos theory that make me wary of believing that just having a logical (cont.)

Comment: ... functor would afford a direct comparison between NNO's along the lines of having an elementary equivalence between them. It could be just a matter of inexperience on my part with models of (bounded) Zermelo set theory and what logical functors between them would entail, and I am open to being convinced by you, but I'm not seeing what you're saying at all clearly yet. 

Comment: Todd, to make it more concrete, if one model has an integer solution to a certain diophantine equation, then I think that the image of that solution under a logical functor would have to satisfy the same equation in the other model. Thus, if the two models disagree about whether there is a solution (which is possible), then there can be no logical functor in that direction.

Comment: Yes, that I agree with (and thanks for putting it concretely). And that certainly answers the first part of David's 3. Do you have a feeling about the second part (he asked whether any two models $E$, $E''$ could be connected by a span $E \leftarrow E' \to E''$, and based on something else he said he might be interested in more elaborate zigzags)? 


Comment: If span just means that there is an $E'$ with logical functors into both, then if the functors are arithemtic-truth-preserving, then there could be no span either when the arithmetic theories of the models of set theory are not the same. But I'm not sure about the extent to which we can expect the functors to be arithmetic truth-preserving---Mike Shulman once told me something definite about this, and perhaps he'll show up here.

Comment: Logical functors between topoi preserve everything that can be expressed in the internal logic of the topoi.  For models of ETCS, that would include not only first-order but also higher-order arithmetic.  As Joel pointed out, even if we consider only models of ETCS that arise from models of (a sufficiently large fragment of) ZFC, they can disagree about many such statements.  Such a disagreement prevents logical morphisms, spans, and even longer zigzags of logical morphisms.  The category of models of ETCS and logical morphisms is therefore badly disconnected.